# $h: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$ continuous $\implies$ $h$ is constant.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

> $h: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$ continuous $\implies$  $h$ is constant.

**Reductio ad absurdum:**

Suppose $h$ is not constant. Since $h$ is continuous, $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists \delta >0 \, \, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$$
But since $h$ is not constant $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq 1$ such that if you choose $\varepsilon = 1/2$ for example, the statement is not true, hence $h$ has to be constant.

Comment: What you wrote is the definition of uniform continuity, not of continuity. In regular continuity $\delta$ might depend on the point, not just on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Such an argument would surely prove that any continuous $f:M\to\Bbb Z$, where $M$ is an arbitrary metric space, is constant.

Comment: Does it matter, Mark? You're right, the $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ has to be behind $\varepsilon >0$.

Comment: Of course it does. And how do you know that there are necessary $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $h(x)\ne h(y)$? Anyway, as @Lord Shark the Unknown wrote in his comment your proof can't be true, because otherwise we could use it in any metric space and get contradictions.

Comment: I'll give a hint to how you can give a correct proof. Suppose there are two different points $x_1,x_2\in h(\mathbb{R})$. Without loss of generality $x_1<x_2$. Since $h$ is continuous, what does the intermediate value theorem tell us?

Comment: The statement is really intuitive and simple, hence i believe that an indirect proof would be more powerful. I might suppose that $h$ is not continuous; deducing that $h$ can't be constant then... Every constant function is continuous.

Comment: Ok, but "$h$ is not continuous implies $h$ is not constant" is not equivalent to "$h$ is continuous implies $h$ is constant". This is not the same thing. Anyway, the hint I wrote should bring you to the solution pretty fast.

Comment: Why are you assuming that that $\mathbb{Z}$ has the discrete topology? The result would be false if it had a different topology.

Comment: @Mark, how is it not the same thing, out of curiosity?  Isnt that just a proof by contraposition?

Comment: No. Contraposition would be "$h$ is not constant implies $h$ is not continuous", not the other way around.

Comment: The IVT tells us that $f$ takes on every value between $[x_1,x_2]$. I know that this can't be true since $\mathbb{Z}\cap (z,z+1)=\{\}$ for $z\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but perhaps he is conjoining the contrapositional argument with a contradiction argument.  You assume the negation of the consequent and to show the negation of antecedent you simply assume its truth and that a contradiction forms.  Thats what it looks like hes doing to me.  I dont think its fallacious. Unless something weird with predicate logic is going on.

Comment: On second thought Im not so sure.  I said it myself plain as day and overlooked it anyway.  You are literally making two assumptions: negation of the consequent and affirming the antecedent. You really cant conclude anything at all from the arising contradiction, but that at least one of the assumptions is faulty. Im not sure if this is a valid proof approach under the circumstances or not.

Comment: Not to appeal to intuition but it does seem fairly obvious that $h$ has to be constant. Suppose it wasnt. In the plot there would necessarily be jump discontinuities with gaps of at least 1, making $h$ discontinuous. Clearly not a rigorous argument.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying... !! But how do it formally?